# ERROR: Cannot find Package - Customizing Notifications with RemoteViews

Tags: java, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap push plugin on cordova.

When i try to build my app, it shows the following errors:

```
Error: /Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:324: error: cannot find symbol
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        ^
  symbol:   class RemoteViews
  location: class GCMIntentService
/Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:324: error: cannot find symbol
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
                                      ^
  symbol:   class RemoteViews
  location: class GCMIntentService
/Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:324: error: package R does not exist
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
                                                                     ^
/Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:325: error: package R does not exist
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image, R.drawable.notification_image);
                                          ^
/Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:325: error: package R does not exist
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image, R.drawable.notification_image);
                                                                   ^
/Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:326: error: package R does not exist
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, fromHtml(extras.getString(TITLE)));
                                     ^
/Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java:327: error: package R does not exist
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, fromHtml(extras.getString(MESSAGE)));
                                     ^
Note: /Users/Lawrence/solvePOS/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I know the problem probably lies with the layout custom_notification.xml file in res/layout. However, when i last checked, it was there.

custom_notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_notification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notification_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/notification_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notification_image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notification_image"
        style="@style/NotificationTitle"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notification_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_title"
        style="@style/NotificationText"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="NotificationText">
    </style>
    <style name="NotificationTitle">
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'm using the following code for createNotification:

```
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image, R.drawable.notification_image);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, fromHtml(extras.getString(TITLE)));
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, fromHtml(extras.getString(MESSAGE)));

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    //.setContentTitle(fromHtml(extras.getString(TITLE)))
                    .setTicker(fromHtml(extras.getString(TITLE)))
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
```

I also have view.View imported:

```
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import android.view.View;
```

Any assistant will be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Got my resource from here: http://www.framentos.com/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/